# do I need to include header files included in other header file in the dependencies list for a make file?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

For example if I have A.h that includes B.h. And I have the source file A.c for A.h. Do i need to include B.h in the dependency list of every sample.c (that calls functions in A.c) while creating makefile ?

Comment: Why don't you try without including them as dependencies and see what happens. The best way to learn, in my experience, is by trying.

Comment: The best practice is to include *all* of the *direct* dependencies. Even if you know some of them are including each other.

Comment: Generate such dependencies automatically. There are sample makefile which provide this. If you are not bound to make, consider a modern build tool which has this feature built-in, e.g. SCons.

Answer (score 1):

You should include all non-system headers, direct and indirect, in the rule for a given source file.

Suppose you have the following:

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct s1 {
    int f1;
};

void f1(int p1);

#endif
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

void f2(struct s1 *p1);

#endif
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"

void f3()
{
    struct s1 my_s1;
    my_s1.f1 = 1;
    my_s1.f2 = 2;
    f2(&my_s1);
}
```

Suppose the definition of `struct s1` in b.h changes to remove the field `f2`.  If b.h is not included in the dependency list for a.c, a.c won't be recompiled.  Then you end up linking the existing object file with another with conflicting definitions for `struct s1`.  You then end up with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So you need to fugure out all dependencies.  Luckily, [gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) has an option to generate the dependency rules for you:

```
gcc -MM a.c
```

This will output a rule suitable for make that has all non-system include files listed, both direct and indirect.

```
a.o: a.c a.h b.h
```